# Let $a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n+2} +...+ \sqrt{2n}}{n^{3/2}}$ calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ using integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

> Let
>
> $$
> a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n+2} +...+ \sqrt{2n}}{n^{3/2}}
> $$

My goal is to calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ using integrals.

### What I have tried so far and got stucked:

Let:
$$f(x) = \sqrt{n + x}$$

Therefore:

$$a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n+2} +...+ \sqrt{2n}}{n^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

Now, I know that there is a relation between the Riemann sum and integrals generally speaking:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\left(a + \frac{k(b-a)}{n}\right) = \int^{b}_{a}f(x) dx
$$

Therefore, what I think I can conlude so far from $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ is:

$$
b = 1, a = 0, f(x) = \sqrt{n + x}
$$

But it seems wrong, $f(x)$ has $n$ in it, which is weird as a constant here, so i am not sure i did the whole correlation quite right.

Comment: You should consider $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$

Comment: Now i see my mistake i think, thanks

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure you understand and can justify the steps in the following:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{n+k}}{n\sqrt n}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+\frac kn}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x}\,dx=\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you it helped alot

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n+2} +...\sqrt{2n}}{n^{3/2}}= \frac1n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 1n} + \sqrt{1+\frac2n} +...\sqrt{1+\frac nn}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right).$$

Comment: Very helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

if we have $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  then
$$ \int_{a-1}^{b} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a}^{b+1} \;  f(x) \; dx   $$
Taking $a=n+1,$ $ b = 2n,$
$$ \int_{n}^{2n} \; \sqrt x \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=n+1}^{2n} \;  \sqrt j \; < \; \int_{n+1}^{2n+1} \;  \sqrt x \; dx   $$
and a suitable antiderivative is $$ \frac{2}{3} n^{3/2}  \; .  $$
$$ \frac{2}{3} (2n)^{3/2} -  \frac{2}{3} (n)^{3/2} < \; \sum_{j=n+1}^{2n} \;  \sqrt j \; < \;  \frac{2}{3} (2n+1)^{3/2} -  \frac{2}{3} (n+1)^{3/2} $$
The left hand side is $$ \frac{2n^{3/2}}{3} (2^{3/2} - 1) $$